# Should tables be dynamically created?

Tags: database, database-design

I'm making an application for collectors where users will upload lists of stuff they want to collect

For example, someone wants to collect flowers and uploads a list of some flowers he'd like to collect which may look something like this:

```
Rose, Chrystanthemums, Narcissus
```

Then they may choose which ones they have and work towards their goal.

Of course, users would be able to upload all kinds of different lists which brings up the question on how should this data be saved and accessed.

An approach i thought of would be to dynamically create a table everytime a user uploads a list, but upon looking it up it's a practice that's generally frowned upon and people usually suggested other alternatives. However i can't quite think of an alternative for my situation.

In [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42366/is-it-a-good-practice-to-create-tables-dynamically-in-a-site?rq=1) question on DBA stack exchange the reply was that there can be a few rare cases where this is a good practice.

Is my case one of those?
How should i go about designing it?

Also i understand that i'm not providing many details about this problem and i'm not asking for you to design this for me. I'm just asking for some general guidelines or a direction to move to.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello @aMimikyu for an example as simple as the one you mention dynamic tables won't be a help, on the contrary migth degrade the performance of your software,  as you can use a single table for storing the users list and then use a column of the table to identify the type of list the user is saving. But in my opinion, there is a case when the dynamic tables migth be usefull: if the entities (abstract representation of data) cannot be managed by the same class (model) on every different type of input. In this case the models and tables can be created on the fly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It looks like i'll have to follow this approach after all.

Comment: It also depends on how are you going to query the database, if you´re going to query on list items, then this items should be represented by a column in your table, but if you´re not quering on list items you can serialize the user lists and save them as a string (kind of a Document DB approach). You should take a look to MongoDB and evaluate if does the work for your app.